# html element isn't registering js click due to negative z-index on parent

Tags: javascript, css

For project critera I am in need of finding a way to have a negative z-index element have a clickable child element inside it but can't figure out the wonky behavior of z-index.

As a result I am unable to figure out a way to get the child element back on top of its parent after setting the parent's z-index to a negative value.

see http://jsfiddle.net/vLkax5yx/6/ for example

How can I make the link that doesn't work onclick event fire?

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the onClick to fire if something is over top of it?  Think of it like if you had a marker and you pressed down on two sheets of paper - where would the mark be left?  You need to either move it to the top or add a different kind of onClick listener through JS, most likely (more intelligent people feel free to correct me)

Comment: Why are you using a negative z-index at all? You should look into using z-index ranges.

Comment: what is your goal? May be there's a different solution

Comment: I think you should probably rephrase your question. I don't think anyone would say "hey I have this project that needs negative z-indexs!". What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe(!) `pointer-events` could help you here, to let clicks “go through” elements you have laying on top … but you should really specify the actual situation more clearly.

Comment: usually child nodes stack on top of their parents. I'm trying to get that behavior with a negative z-indexed element.

Comment: the Reason I need this is due to there being another element above the grey box, a navigation bar, that has dropdown fields. These fields have a negative z-index to make sure they drop down behind their parent, but in order for the alert box to be behind the dropdowns the alert's z-index needs to be lower then the negative z-index on the dropdown nodes. I'll create another jsfiddle to help explain the reasoning.

Comment: okay here's a jsfiddle example of this - http://jsfiddle.net/vLkax5yx/9/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you can't. The `z-index` CSS property exists for a reason, and it's functionality doesn't allow something like this to be done. I was thinking about `event bubbling` for a second, but that's for *stopping an event* on an element that is on-top of one that already has an event, not creating one from thin air.

Comment: I really need that ability.  Otherwise the alert will appear in front of the dropdowns. The dropdowns have a negative z-index value to get them behind their parent element (if you change it to positive even if it's lower then their parent the child will appear in front of the parent).  example: jsfiddle.net/vLkax5yx/9